# node test module is returning an error for the test

Tags: node.js, npm, automated-tests

I am new to programming in node and would like to request help. I have been trying to test a reactive native app in with appium and other drivers however when I try to execute the script first it returns the following error, files are inside test folder:

```
 npm test

> demo_app@1.0.0 test
> ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\demo_app>
```

And I passed trough a tutorial where they mention that I need to put node before the command on this script

```
 "scripts": {
  "test": " ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js\""
  },
```

So I did and it became this

```
 "scripts": {
  "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js\""
  },
```

And the error now becomes this:
(the files are inside test/...)

```
   npm test 
  > demo_app@1.0.0 test
  > node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"

   C:\demo_app\node_modules\.bin\wdio:2
  basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
      ^^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Please if somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have issues with extra special characters? Can you please try:

```
 "scripts": {
  "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
```

Comment: Good point however same error